# Many buttons not functioning in WordPress dashboard (as admin)

Tags: posts, ajax, jquery, wp-admin, errors

I am having issues with many functions in the dashboard of one of my sites. For example, when I try to click on a tab in any of my plugins (e.g. to change settings), it doesn't do anything. Also, when I click on any of the "edit" buttons (e.g. to change status of a post), they don't do anything.

I'm intermittently getting this error in the console, though I'm not sure if it's related:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasClass' of undefined
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (wp-auth-check.min.js?ver=5.0.2:1)
at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)
at HTMLDocument.r.handle (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)
at Object.trigger (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)
at Object.a.event.trigger (jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1:2)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)
at Function.each (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
at a.fn.init.each (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
at a.fn.init.trigger (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)
at Object.<anonymous> (heartbeat.min.js?ver=5.0.2:1)
```

which is coming from this file: wp-auth-check.min.js?ver=5.0.2:1

Also, when I navigate anywhere in the dashboard, this appears once in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createElement' of undefined
at SGPBGutenbergBlock.init (gutenbergBlock.min.js?ver=3.1.4.1:9)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (gutenbergBlock.min.js?ver=3.1.4.1:170)
at i (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
at Function.ready (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
at HTMLDocument.K (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
```

which is from this file: gutenbergBlock.min.js?ver=3.1.4.1:9

Not sure why this started happening and can't seem to find a solution after Googling around for quite some time.

As I said the first error just happens intermittently; when I click one of the non-functioning tabs/buttons, nothing appears in the console.

I'm guessing there is some sort of error with jQuery/AJAX? Please let me know if any more information is needed -- I'm not very experienced with this stuff. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Some more possibly relevant info; I am using SimpleMag child theme, and when I try to customize the appearance, a blank screen shows with no menu options.

Comment: Try temporarily deactivating plugins and switching themes (to a default theme) to see if the error goes away.  Then enable one at a time to see which is causing the error.